# New version of PHP file upload times out. Old one fine.?

Tags: php, file, upload

Maybe I have a mental block of some kind but this problem is bugging me...
I have an app, for a photography club, whereby images files are uploaded and moved to a folder, and the titles store din a MySQL database. his all works fine.
Recently the requirment changed, so I am amending the app. To do this while leaving the existing app running I copied the PHP files and renamed then with a suffix of X. I also duplicated a couple of the MySQL tables with a suffix X.
Obviously, I then modified the 'X' code.

The problem is that when I reach the stage of inputting a file name and submitting it falls over with a timeout. The log says:

"[Sun Dec 11 00:08:57 2016] [warn] [client 82.20.120.43] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper, referer: http://www.rdps.co.uk/comp/en-entriesX.php"

"[Sun Dec 11 00:08:57 2016] [error] [client 82.20.120.43] Script timed out before returning headers: cgi_wrapper, referer: http://www.rdps.co.uk/comp/en-entriesX.php"

'EntriesX.php' is the prog that puts up the form for the users to fill in with file names. This feeds into 'EntriesUpdX.php'.

The original version of the app still runs fine. I've gone over the code a lot, but I can't see what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: We are just as clueless as you, if not more, without some code examples, maybe try adding some or trying to track down where the script stops responding

Comment: Well, I have tried putting in debugging lines, but none seem to be executed. The thing I find hard to understand is that the old code and new code are, on the face of it, essentially the same, just with some different handling of the data and some radio buttons I have now put in.
Obviously something I've done has upset things but I'm struggling to see what.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[max_execution_time][1]` in `php.ini`

Or in php code: [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. However, on trying it, it made no difference.
The thing is, the old code runs fine, and quickly. The new code is essentially the same, it just handles the data differently, so there shouldn't be any significant difference in the execution time. I think it is hanging in some way, but I can't see where or why.

Comment: More info - even if I don't enter any file names at all it still times out. In this case the app should just do nothing, which shouldn't take too long! Hence, it is waiting for something (before) actually running - but what?